# How can I highlight the active line in Visual Studio, without using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio

How can I highlight the active line in Visual Studio 2005 and/or 2008?  I would like the current line to be highlighted as other IDE's and text editors do, such as Eclipse and UltraEdit.  ReSharper [can do this](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/screenshots/40/assistance_highlight_current_line.png), but it comes at additional costs.

Comment: I'd love to be able to do this without slowing down the text editor.

Comment: I'm using dommer's method of using SlickEdit.  I haven't noticed any slowdown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SlickEdit Gadgets](http://www.slickedit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=78&Itemid=90) have a free "line ruler" gadget that does this.

Comment: This worked.  I previously overlooked it assuming that it required the tick marks.  The tick marks can be turned off in the options.  Thanks!

Comment: This works, but it is too slow for me.  I can't move my cursor around nearly as quickly.  This makes it a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 with the Productivity Power Tools extension.  I know--doesn't answer the question; then again, this wasn't an option when the question was written. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it out-of-the-box

Using resharper or another addin that has this feature is your only option.